# Maximum of all averages with join in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Tables (GRADES,COURSES) and i need to find the COURSE_ID with the Maximum Average of all Averages of Courses Grades

**Example :**

```
DBASE COURSE GRADES : 90,60,90,100 (AVGERAGE=85)
DSTRUCT COURSE GRADES : 100,100,100,100 (AVERAGE=100)
C# COURSE GRADES : 50,50,60,60 (AVERAGE = 55)
```

So i should get the COURSE_ID of the course (DSTRUCT) which its the MAXIMUM average of all averages

I started with this and am getting syntax error !

```
SELECT COURSE_ID
FROM COURSES
HAVING MAX(SELECT AVG(GRADE) 
FROM COURSES,
WHERE
COURSES.COURSE_ID=GRADES.COURSE_ID);
```

Comment: try making one query that finds the averages. Then use that as the FROM () clause - then in the wrapper query, select the MAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I did misunderstood your question before)

So you are not able to use the `order by ... desc`, and not `with .. as...`

and I think you are into doing standard sql, as you did not mention used sql server.
No row limitation etc.

This is not a nice solution, but it does what you want with just simple syntax `using max() and group by`.

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ccfc/1**

```
select 
  g.course_id, c.course
from (
  select 
    course_id, 
    avg(grade) as average
  from 
    grades
  group by course_id  
  ) g,
  courses c
where 
g.course_id = c.course_id
and g.average = (
  select 
    max(g1.average) 
  from (
    select 
      course_id, 
      avg(grade) as average
    from 
      grades
    group by course_id  
    ) g1
  )
;
```

---

result

```
COURSE_ID   COURSE
---------   ------
2           dstruct
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ccfc/1)**
**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ccfc/1**

Comment: can you edit the code so it would display in the output only the course_id ? i dont need the course name

Comment: Yeah great , just one more thing , can you write the query without assigning "g" and "c" and "g1"?

Comment: As you use oracle it is no problem to remove the alias, in other databases you might get error (e.g. mysql). Check the sqlfiddle which is compiled for oracle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9f8a/3

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76db83/1)

[SQL Server - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d561/4)

**Query 1**:

Using a named sub-query (if there are multiple courses with the same highest average grade then this will return all of them):

```
WITH avg_grades AS (
  SELECT   course_id,
           AVG( grade ) AS avg_grade
  FROM     grades
  GROUP BY course_id 
)
SELECT course_id
FROM   avg_grades
WHERE  avg_grade = ( SELECT MAX( avg_grade ) FROM avg_grades )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76db83/1/0)**:

```
| COURSE_ID |
|-----------|
|         2 |
```

**Query 2**:

Using an analytical function (if there are multiple courses with the same highest average grade then this will return only one of them - the one with the greatest `course_id`):

```
SELECT MAX( course_id ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY avg_grade DESC ) AS course_id
FROM ( SELECT   course_id,
                AVG( grade ) AS avg_grade
       FROM     grades
       GROUP BY course_id )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76db83/1/1)**:

```
| COURSE_ID |
|-----------|
|         2 |
```

Comment: It Works, but is there anyway i can do it without "WITH" because i didnt learn it ,the rest i totally understand it .. but the "WITH" i dont